# Serialising a simple C# function for insertion into and retrieval from an SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, deserialization

I'm developing a feature for a database-driven application written in C# / ASP.NET MVC and used by several organisations. Part of this involves a simple system for assigning a score to particular user inputs A and B, which are both integers.

Each organisation has its own method for generating a score from A and B, which can be expressed as the type `Func<int, int, int>`. This function is only going to require basic operators - for example, it might be `A * B` or `(A * 2) + B`. This needs to be saved to and retrieved from the current organisation's database, and then executed when needed.

I've attempted to serialise an instance of `Func<int, int, int>` but, of course, it doesn't implement `ISerializable`. How to proceed? Is there some alternative way I can store and execute this function? Is this even possible without resorting to some kind of custom parsing code?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't even if possible, for example storing C# code to compile server side or directly binary assemblies to load). (security). If you do not require esoteric logic then simply use NCalc (or any small easy to use parser you want to)  and store expression as string.

Comment: There are a wide range of expression parsers and compilers available for .NET - heck, you cold probably hack one together in Roslyn pretty easily. Would it be simplest just to store the string and use one of those at runtime?

Comment: If you are a fan of clasics you can look at the [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) :)

Comment: A function is *logic*, not data. It gets *compiled*, not serialized. It would be better for your sanity and that of the end users if you stored the expression and parsed it. There are many parser libraries and generators. You could define a basic syntax in a few lines using F#'s Fparsec library for example

Comment: I should have specified that this expression isn't open to change by users directly - it will be set by the developers on behalf of the organisation. The reason for storing it in the db is simply a case of consistency - we have a lookup table in each organisation's db which contains all the custom configuration, which keeps the repo free of any client-specific data.

I'm glad it seems like a common problem with a lot of solutions, it's just something I've never run in to before. Ideally I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Will take a look at my options based on these comments, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I decided to store a simple expression in the database as a string, and use [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](https://flee.codeplex.com/) for the actual evaluation.